# How would you size the transistors in this problem?

Tags: cmos, vlsi

[image]

I know that whenever you have series transistors multiply the equivalent W/L of the inverter by the number of series transistors. In the parallel case W/L remains the same. I don't know how to apply those two rules to this problem. All of the examples I can find are far simpler than this and more symmetric.

How do I apply parallel and series rules to transistors?

Comment: Start by drawing the transistor level schematic of this function, ignore the W/L first, just draw the circuit. After that worry about W/L

Comment: that's not the problem i already drew it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have already sketched out the transistor diagrams take the worst case N path (4 transistors if I am not mistaken) and size these to give you the required overall w/l. The other transistors on the N side can be smaller, you have a set of three one of which is already sized from the above. Size the other two to match the needed overall W/L. Finally you have one which acts on its own size that one accordingly.

Repeat the exercise for the P side transistors and you are done.

Comment: okey, so they can be the same size as the critical path ?!

Comment: Yes they can but silicon area is expensive and the extra gate capacitance reduces performance you would get  extra marks from me for making them as small as possible.